# Using lookup,match, and indirect function

Tags: excel

First off thank you for your time. 
I am having a little bit of an issue with an excel formula. This formula works but the problem I am having is that I need it for multiple cells with multiple sheets. Instead of writing 'Original Copy Center' I'd rather refer it to a cell that has a sheet name.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(MATCH('Original Copy Center'!10:10,'Original Copy Center'!10:10)),'Original Copy Center'!9:9)
```

I came up with the following formula, but with no success.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(MATCH((INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!A10:Z10")),(INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!A10:Z10")))),(INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!A10:Z10")))
```

Regards

Comment: Well that other formula works in the sense that `INDIRECT` successfully refers to a sheet whose name is in `A3`. Otherwise the formula does not seem to make sense to me. What did want to achieve by `MATCH('Original Copy Center'!10:10,'Original Copy Center'!10:10)`?

Comment: Using INDIRECT function you can write `'Original Copy Center'!A10:Z10` as `INDIRECT(A3 & "!A10:Z10")`. But your formula doesn't seems to be correct.